# How to check for two way unique record in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm not sure how this would work, but I run into this issue a lot. If there was just one primary key, I could work with that, but theres 2 that need to be unique.

I have to check every time before I create  anew record, is there no Laravel magic that I can use to check behind the scenes if something like this exists already?

I'm not sure if a two way primary key is something Laravel offers, I don't really know what to be looking for in their documentation but was wondering if one could help?

```
if (CourseEntry::where('course_id', $course->id)->where('user_id', Auth::user()->id)->count() < 1) {
    CourseEntry::create([
        'course_id' => $course->id,
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id,
        'last_interaction' => Carbon::now(),
        'started_at' => Carbon::now()
    ]);
}
```

I have a relationship in my `User.php` that could maybe help?

```
public function courseEntries() {
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\CourseEntry');
}
```

Comment: Do you know any SQL? Laravel isn't here to remove worrying about SQL and data models. Yes, you can have a unique key defined in your migration. Checking if something exists before inserting is an antipattern and not the way things are done if you want to ensure uniqueness.

Comment: I understand MySQL supports unique key, but does it support multi unique keys? I understand this is an SQL question, but its using the Laravel migration blueprint system, no SQL is used.

Comment: There can be **only one** primary key, it can be identified by 1 or more columns. There can be **multiple unique** keys, defined by 1 or more columns. Laravel migration is not magic, it ties in to underlying database engine which makes it an SQL related question. You can define these keys in migrations.

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you want to do with the result, as I can guess based on the columns that you would like to update the last interaction of the user with a particular course you can achieve that like this:

```
$courseEntry = CourseEntry::firstOrNew([ 
        'course_id' => $course->id,
        'user_id' => Auth::user()->id 
    ],
    [
        'started_at' => Carbon::now() // this should be set just the first time, when the user entry does not exists
    ]);

$courseEntry->last_interaction = Carbon::now(); // this should be updated each time.
$courseEntry->save();
```

Comment: This is shorter and a little simplified for sure, but I'll await another answer as I feel there is a better way that is more simplified.